# Position Text in the Top Right?

Tags: firebase, flutter

How can I position the text so the username and email in the top right corner? Its the whole time in the top left corner. Nothing works for me pls help?

```
 Center(
         child: Column(
           children: <Widget> [
             Center(
               child: FutureBuilder(
      future: getUserInfo(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                 return ListTile(
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data.data()["Email"], style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                ),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data.data()["Username"], style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                fontSize: 25.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),);});
                } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                 return Text("No data");}
                 return Center(
                  child: SpinKitFadingCircle(color: Colors.white, size: 20.0),
      );
      },
      ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
```

[this is my Profile Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OynrP.png)

This is my edit script but it only Shows the SpinKitFadingCircle.

```
  Column(
           children: <Widget> [
              FutureBuilder(
      future: getUserInfo(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        return Text(snapshot.data.data()["Username"], style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
          fontSize: 15.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
        );

                } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                 return Text("No data");}
                 return Center(
                  child: SpinKitFadingCircle(color: Colors.white, size: 20.0),
      );
      },
      ),
           ],
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
         ),
```

Comment: Can you please add a screen shot it will be more helpful

Comment: You have so much unnecessary center widgets, unnecessary listview.builder, and listTile, you have to use only 2 text and one Column column property is crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end

Comment: `Wrap` your title text with `Row` widget and use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 'textalign' and give it as 'TextAlign.right'.